# VS Code to filter out undesired files from the "Quick Open" file selection list

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

In Visual Studio Code, when I invoke "Quick Open" aka "Go to File" command (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> for Mac, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> for Linux/Windows) and start typing the file name, I see a lots of undesired choices appear. At the moment, I am working on Android, and I see `*.class` and `*.dex` files and when a class has inner classes then it gets even more messy. Also, because of the deep file tree hierarchies, I have created some convenience symbolic links to nested directories (so that it is easy to operate on them from the command line) and I get many duplicates. There is an awful lot of clutter!

The fundamental question regarding "Quick Open": **what facilities are there to restrict the choices in the "Quick Open" file selection list?**

I seek to understand the big picture, and what is available there, but specifically I wish to find solution to the following:

1. Is it possible to ignore files per its extensions (preferably both globally and project-wide)?
2. Is it possible to ignore files programmatically (for example by regular expression match to detect automatically generated files in a project)?
3. Is it possible to specify paths that should be ignored for the files provided by "Quick Open"?
4. Is it possible to ignore all symbolic links within the project?
5. Is there a different way to find files to open than the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> thing, perhaps an extension that replaces or complements the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I found there is the configuration option `Features` / `Search` / `Search: Exclude` that allows specifying the file name pattern to exclude files and paths from the search. This seems to address the most important requirements that I have regarding the "Quick Search" behavior.